# Datatype missmatch with Running Value function in SSRS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have an expression:

```
=RunningValue ( CInt(Fields!Quantity.Value) * CInt(Fields!Vol.Value),SUM, Nothing)
```

Initially I haven't added CInt , but I suspect the data type missmatch issue, so I tried adding with it.

In SQL side, both of these are Int type.

But, inside my deployment environment, it still showing #Error.
I have no idea how to correct it. Kindly help, please.
Thanks

Comment: what are the types of Quantity and Vol in your database?

Answer (score 1):

Check for nulls.

I'm guessing you have null values coming back. Use the IsNothing function.

e.g.    `IsNothing(yourFieldValue,0)`

Comment: RunningValue(IsNothing(Fields!Quantity.Value,0) * (IsNothing(Fields!Vol.Value),0),SUM,Nothing))  Something like that? still my written expression is incorrect . Sorry I am not very familiar with SSRS.

Comment: You have more ")" than "(" in your expression.

Comment: My bad.Is it correct now ? =RunningValue(IsNothing(Fields!Quantity.Value,0) * IsNothing(Fields!Vol.Value,0),SUM,Nothing)  #error : too many arguments to public function IsNothing. I think they allow to use only one IsNothing.

Comment: =RunningValue ( SUM(IIF(Fields!Quantity.Value Is Nothing , CInt(0), CInt (Fields!Quantity.Value)) * IIF(FieldsVol.Value Is Nothing, CInt(0),CInt(Fields!Vol.Value))),SUM, Nothing)  I 've changed all the possible value into same datatype and used Is Nothing. It works fine in RDL but still having error in c#.

Comment: At the risk of teaching you how to suck eggs... 1. There is no point in CInt(0).... 2. I really don't know what "still having the error in c#" means... this is SSRS.... 3. If you are having problems with **any** bit of code strip it down to the most basic part and then build it up again step by step until the error presents itself...

Comment: @BI Developer Okay Thank you. 2) I know it is SSRS issue, what I really want to mean is the error occurs when I run that RDLC in the c# program.